# Padding in Keccak SHA3 hashing algorithm

Tags: sha-3, keccak

In FIPS-202 specification, the padding required for SHA3 were not clearly mentioned. so we have analyzed the NIST test vectors for SHA3, which states that append "0x06" (never used 1 followed by 'j'zeros and then 1 specified in FIPS-202) to the message digest, which is a contradiction to the specification.

The link for NIST test vector is :-

http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/examples.html#aHashing

http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/documents/Examples/SHA3-224_Msg0.pdf

could you clarify padding mechanism  for SHA3?

Answer (score 10):

> In FIPS-202 specification, the padding required for SHA3 were not clearly mentioned.

I beg to differ. From the [FIPS 202.](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.202.pdf) section B2.:

> For most applications, the message is byte-aligned, i.e., $len(M)
> = 8m$ for a nonnegative integer $m$.
>
> In  this  case,  the  total  number  of bytes,  denoted  by $q$,
>   that  are  appended  to  the  message is determined as follows by 
>   $m$ and the rate $r$:
>   $$q = \frac{r}{8} – (m \bmod{\frac{r}{8}})$$
>
> The  value  of $q$ determines  the  hexadecimal  form  of these  bytes
>   in  this  case according  to  the conversion  functions specified in  Sec.  B.1.  The  padded  messages  that  result  are  summarized  in 
>   Table 6:
>
> ```
> +-------------------------+--------------------------------+
> |                         |                                |
> | Number of padding bytes |       Padded message           |
> |                         |                                |
> +----------------------------------------------------------+
> |                         |                                |
> |         q = 1           |  M || 0x86                     |
> |                         |                                |
> |         q = 2           |  M || 0x0680                   |
> |                         |                                |
> |         q > 2           |  M || 0x06 || 0x00... || 0x80  |
> |                         |                                |
> +-------------------------+--------------------------------+
> ```
>
> the notation `0x00...` indicates the string that consists of $q – 2 $ “zero” bytes.

If you look at your [test vector](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/documents/Examples/SHA3-224_Msg0.pdf), for $\operatorname{SHA3-224}$. $224$ means $224$ bits of security. So we have $c = 224 \times 2 = 448$ and $r = 1600 - c = 1152$.

Because message is empty, $len(M) = 0$, therefore $m = 0$. Hence $$q = \frac{1152}{8} - 0 \bmod \frac{1152}{8} = 144$$

Therefore we are in the third case: ($q > 2$).

The padding will be : `0x06 || 144 - 2 zeros || 0x80`.
Therefore we find back the `data to be absorbed` :

```
06 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 80
```

`06` followed by 284 `0` (or 142 `00`) then followed by `80`. The followings `00` are provided to show that the capacity won't change during the absorption.

Answer (score 5):

Your confusion comes from the SHA-03 domain, the padding is as specified 10*1; however when you prepend the domains to the padding you get:

```
domain    result         used in
  01     M||0110*1     SHA3-224 to 512
  11     M||1110*1     RawSHAKE128 or 256
 1111    M||111110*1   SHAKE128 or 256
```

Answer (score 0):

in chapter 5, the padding function pad: P = 1 || 0^j || 1 ,has two purposes, one for example, another one is, it shows a multi-rate padding for a bit-aligned message.

however, the message in sha3 is byte-aligned, so another multi-rate padding function is provided in Appendix B.2.